# MySQL How to return rows where values are found in another table

Tags: mysql

I have a recipe application with two main tables structured as follows;

### recipes

- id
- title

### recipe_ingredients

- id
- recipe_id
- name
- full_description

Where recipe_ingredients contains multiple rows linked to a recipe and holds information on each individual ingredient.

I'm trying to perform a search on the database to return all recipes that contain both 'chicken' and 'rice' as an ingredient, but my current query returns no results as I believe it's searching for ingredients where chicken and rice are a single ingredient(row).

Here's my query;

```
SELECT r.* FROM recipe AS r
INNER JOIN recipe_ingredient AS ri ON ri.recipe_id = r.id
WHERE (ri.name LIKE '%chicken%' OR ri.full_description LIKE '%chicken%') AND (ri.name LIKE '%rice%' OR ri.full_description LIKE '%rice%')
GROUP BY r.id
```

The above query returns no results at all, but there are recipes in the database which have both chicken and rice as an ingredient.

Answer (score 2):

This fails as soon as a recipe has an ingredient that is neither rice nor chicken; you have to use an inner query that looks whether a given ingredient exists for each recipe.

Something like this:

```
SELECT r.* FROM recipe AS r
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM recipe_ingredient ri
    WHERE ri.recipe_id = r.id
    AND (ri.name LIKE '%chicken%' OR ri.full_description LIKE '%chicken%')
)
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM recipe_ingredient ri
    WHERE ri.recipe_id = r.id
    AND (ri.name LIKE '%rice%' OR ri.full_description LIKE '%rice%')
)
```

This is not really elegant but you get what I meant.